# Stephen Hawking's theory of multiple universes

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, multiverse

Is it correct to think that there are multiple universes?
Does my thinking of having more than one big bang?

Comment: Define *universe*. (Obviously, you can't have the customary meaning of "all that there is" if you're going to have multiples)

Comment: I was reading one of his work so in which he mentioned about it so I thought it would be his theory

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question but I'll try and answer it. I'll not include any mathematics in my answer. If you would like me to get into technical details then let me know and I'll edit my answer. The idea of multiverses has found resonance in multiple places in theoretical physics but I think Brian Greene's categorization of multiverses is perhaps the must lucid. According to Brian Greene there can be 9 types of multiverses.

Quilted, Inflationary, Brane, Cyclic, Landscape, Quantum, Holographic, Simulated and Ultimate.

I'll explain a few of them. Obviously all of them are complex theoretical models in their own right and require in-depth study.

The Quilted multiverse is very simple. It is a consequence of infinite space. If space is infinite then all events will occur infinitely. However, because of the limit on speed of light, we can only observe small part of this universe. This is called our cosmic horizon.

The Inflationary multiverse is a consequence of the Big Bang theory itself. Some people refer to it as eternal inflation. The idea is that some volume of the Universe is always under inflation and this process (through quantum fluctuations of the inflation field) essentially spawns bubbles creating new universes.

The Brane multiverse is a direct consequence of the M-theory which is kind of like amalgamation of the different flavors of the string theory. The idea is that our universe is 3 dimensional and exists inside a higher dimension space with other universes.

The Quantum multiverse is a weird theory. Some physicists believe that under quantum phenomenon there is no uncertainty and that all possible outcomes happen but in parallel universes. So if an electron resolves from a superposition, then it resolves to all possible positions in different universes. We observe the one of position in our universe. This to us appears as uncertainty but behind it is a deterministic system.

I hope that helps. Let me know if you want me to get into details about any of them and I can try and elaborate.

Also, I am not sure why you refer to the multiverse theories as Stephen Hawking's theory of multiple universes. Hawking has no doubt contributed to some multiverse theories but they are by no means, his theories.